# EXCEL: How to create folders that autoupdate as I insert a new value?

Tags: excel, create-directory, vba

I want to create folders with Excel, in a way that every time a make a new entry in the selected column, a new folder is created.

I already searched and found some codes to VBA that creates the folders. But I have to select the cells and then run the macro everytime. Is there any way that I can do that automatically?

Thank you in advance,
Leo

Below is the code for creating new folders (Sub directories)

```
Sub CreateFolder() 
Dim caminho As String 
Dim folder As Object, FolderName 

For i = 1 To 500 
    Set folder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") FolderName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("A" & i).Value 
    If Not folder.FolderExists(FolderName) Then 
        folder.CreateFolder (FolderName) 
    End If 
    directory = ThisWorkbook.Path 
Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: Do some more searching. Start with "Excel vba Events" and in particular, `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: Just so we are on the same page, can you define "folder"?

Comment: @JohnMuggins Litteraly the regular folder. I have this code:

Sub CreateFolder()
    Dim caminho As String
    Dim folder As Object, FolderName
 
   For i = 1 To 500
          
    Set folder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FolderName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("A" & i).Value
    
   If Not folder.FolderExists(FolderName) Then
        folder.CreateFolder (FolderName)
   End If
   
directory = ThisWorkbook.Path
   Next i
End Sub

Comment: @JohnMuggins This code alows me to create a folder in the same directory where the excel is saved, and it's working. The only thing is that every time i put a new value i have to run the macro. I know that its possible to do that automaticly (when i put a new value, automaticly runs the macro and creates the folder) but i can't figure out how. Can you help me? :) 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can help you.  Just need some pertinent info.  Does the column need to be selected?  Or can you work with a hard coded column?  Say a column like Column D...    We can put a Worksheet_Change macro on your worksheet module so that whenever a value in a certain column is changed - it will automatically check to see if that folder exists and if not then create it.

Here is an example that will create folders for any new or changed cells in column D:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim caminho As String
Dim folder As Object, FolderName

If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Value <> "" Then ' If Changed Cell is in Column A


'   This code changes unacceptable file name characters with an underscore
    Filename = Target.Value
    MyArray = Array("<", ">", "|", "/", "*", "\", "?", """")
    For X = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        Filename = Replace(Filename, MyArray(X), "_", 1)
    Next X

'   This code creates the folder if it doesn't already exist
    Set folder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FolderName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Filename
    If Not folder.FolderExists(FolderName) Then
        folder.CreateFolder (FolderName)
    End If



End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I changed the code above to react whenever someone enters something into column A.  Put the above macro into your worksheet module, not a regular module.  In the vba editor double click on the worksheet object and its module will open.  Paste the above code into that module.  Then go into the sheet and type something into column A and hit enter when done.  It will automatically check to see if a folder by that name exists, and if not it will create one.  There are some illegal characters for filenames and I have replaced those with an underscore so it won't throw an error when creating folder.